# Стилизация вкладок в guake

Tags: linux, terminal

Пользую альтернативу терминалу [guake](https://github.com/Guake/guake), доволен. Но, как всегда хочется большего.
 Если есть информация о том существует ли такая возможность в **guake**, для разных вкладок использовать разное оформление и сохранять состояние вкладок после выключения, дайте знать
Спасибо

Comment: Могу посоветовать в качестве альтернативы [Tilda](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda), сам недавно пересел на него с Guake. Он на каждый запускаемый процесс (в каждом может быть несколько вкладок) создаёт отдельный конфиг, в котором можно менять положение, оформление, горячие клавиши.

Comment: @D-side  я некоторое время назад пересел с тильды на гуак. это не то что меня интересует, спасибо

Comment: @username, вас действительно интересует ответ «да|нет»?

Comment: @alexander barakin если есть варианты стилизации, то возможно о них тут отпишут

Comment: @username, теперь вопрос превратился в классический «опросник». может быть, всё-таки, лучше его конкретизировать? типа: «как добавить в этот фрагмент кода возможность задать разное оформление для вкладок?» и приложить соответствующий фрагмент из исходников guake.

Comment: @alexander barakin я понял что Вы заботитесь о порядке, но Ваше замечание не конструктивно.

Comment: @alexander barakin
http://guake.org/ - скидываю ссылку чтобы быть увереным что Вы поняли вопрос. Я не собираюсь переписывать данное ПО под себя. Вопрос о возможностях настройки ПО, о котором я не знаю, с помощью окружения или настроек данного ПО. О котором упоминал D-side но для другого ПО

Comment: Тоже использую **guake**, отдельное оформление для разных вкладок не встречал. Сохранять состояние при перезагрузке - также не видел такой опции. Но можно настроить автозагрузку самостоятельно, написав bash-скрипт, чтобы автоматически заданные [вкладки guake](http://jeka.by/post/1031/guake-tabs-control/) открывались после загрузки. guake --new-tab='tab1' --rename-tab='mysql local' --execute-command='mysql -u root'